# How to connect two or more mp4 files?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, vlc, video-editor, mp4

I have two mp4 files (part 1 and part 2 of a video with sound), and when one ends I want the other to begin, but this gets a little annoying because it is a music video and the sound has to stop while I am launching the new one, so I am wondering if there is any way of making it so that they become one file? I am downloading the mp4 files using VLC Player (I am streaming them from YouTube), so would it perhaps be possible to somehow instruct VLC Player or another player that I could download them with to do this automatically? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: I would opt "OpenShot Video Editor" for this job.. :-)

Comment: Openshot or ffmpeg I guess. No time to write answer, but there are tutorials about both.

Comment: Here's for command line: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161226/how-to-join-video-files-from-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround ...

> - Download your videos

Instead of downloading your videos using VLC, download them using **clipgrab**.

It is a **little tiny (275KB of size) free and easy to use portable tool**
which lets you download videos from Youtube and many other sites.

**Just [*Download it*](http://clipgrab.org/) ->Extract it -> double click on it ...  ;-)**

[image]

> - Now joining them all with [OpenSHot Video Editor](http://www.openshot.org/ppa/)

You can find **numerous ways** to achieve this. I use OpenShot.

- Installing OpenShot :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa -y
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
  ```

Using this method provides you with the **latest** version.

OpenShot is also available in the standard repositories and can be installed with:

```
   sudo apt-get install openshot
```

- Joining Videos :

  Drag and drop all the videos to be joined into Openshot as shown.

[image]

Drag and drop each of them into any of the tracks one after the other joining them as you require.

[image]

Go to File-> Export - Save it with whichever name and format you want.

If you want to do this from terminal, good answers are available :

[How to join video files from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161226/how-to-join-video-files-from-terminal)

Comment: And there is no way of doing this through VLC Player automatically rather than using additional software (see my updated question)?

Comment: There are many features in VLC, one of them which you might be interested in is "Merge and Transcode Multiple Videos" ( [more details](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Merge_and_Transcode_Multiple_Videos/) ), but this needs "your video and audio codecs to be appropriate". But using **clipgrab** and Openshot is the best way I know for this job ;-) @ParanoidPanda

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the VLC Media Player to join/merge multiple video files. Open a Terminal in the folder with the video files and then type:

```
vlc InFile1.mp4 InFile2.mp4 --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=OutFile.mp4}" --sout-keep
```

This opens up VLC GUI and you can close it once the files are joined/merged. You can find more info [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Merge_and_Transcode_Multiple_Videos/).

It seems this can also be achieved through VLC GUI but I never go that working properly.