# combining mp4 files returns bad argument

Tags: android, iphone, avconv

I'm currently trying to combine converted mp4 files into 1 mp4 file but it's not going that great. To see my previous question, which includes some real struggle with filters and settings, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860260/audio-desynced-from-avconv-commands/862325).

The steps I'm currently doing are:

Step 1: Scale the title video

```
avconv -i "templates/v2/wiebenik-v2.mov" -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2" -aspect "16:9" -profile:v high -level 42 -c:a copy -y "templates/v2/wiebenik-v2_libx264.mp4"
```

Step 2: Normalize the audio for the title video

```
avconv -i "templates/v2/wiebenik-v2_libx264.mp4" -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -profile:v high -level 42 -aspect "16:9" templates/v2/wiebenik-v2_libx264_normalized.mp4
```

Step 3&4: scale and normalize the video from the user

```
avconv -i "44_0.98330200-14823142026903.mp4" -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2" -profile:v high -level 42 -c:a copy -aspect "16:9" -y "videos/test.mp4"
avconv -i "videos/test.mp4" -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -aspect "16:9" test_normalized.mp4
```

Step 5: combine the videos

```
MP4Box templates/v2/wiebenik-v2_libx264_normalized.mp4 -cat test_normalized.mp4 -out test_video.mp4
```

This'll return the error:

```
WARNING: Concatenating track ID 1 with different SPS - result file might be broken
```

---

I've also tried to compile the video's differently, as shown in the following list:

```
avconv -i "videos/templates/v2/wiebenik-v2.mov" -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2" -profile:v high -level 42 -c:a copy -y "videos/templates/v2/wiebenik-v2.mp4"
avconv -i "videos/templates/v2/wiebenik-v2.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 videos/templates/v2/wiebenik-v2_normalized.mp4
avconv -i 33_0.57471800-14821542544448.mp4 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2" -profile:v high -level 42 -c:a copy tmp_ruud_1.mp4
avconv -i tmp_ruud_1.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 tmp_ruud_1_normalized.mp4
MP4Box wiebenik-v6_normalized.mp4 -cat tmp_ruud_1_normalized.mp4 -out test_video2.mp4
```

Which did work, for iPhone 7 videos (kind of.. it froze halfway on an iPhone but worked on an android device). Android will still break its head while trying to convert it. That'll return the error:

```
WARNING: Concatenating track ID 1 with different SPS - result file might be broken
Error appending tmp_44_0_normalized.mp4: Bad Parameter
```

The thing that's weird though is that `MP4Box -info <filename>` both returns the same SPS settings for both attempts. I would love to get a solution after 2 weeks of fighting with this.

- Still waiting for an answer